# How to find Foursquare Page USER_ID?

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to use the Foursquare Page endpoint: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/pages/pages

Which is supposed to look like this: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/pages/USER_ID?oauth_token=XXX

However I'm unclear on what the USER_ID value should be.  For example, I'd like to get the Page info for https://foursquare.com/dbmagazine

I tried setting the USER_ID value to "dbmagazine" but I get a 400 response back saying "Must provide a valid page ID".

Is there some other identifier I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the numeric user id for the page.

To get the User ID from the page's twitter handle ("dbmagazine"), you can use the [users/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/search) endpoint, with the parameter twitter set to dbmagazine.